# Do I need to consider user context when working with Twitter API here?

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

I'm building a small system which allows a user to login to the system, put a query and retrieve tweets 'relevant' to the query. I also want to get user's past tweets, his followee/er ids and his profile information.

So this [twitter api page](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview) says,

> In order to make authorized calls to Twitter’s APIs, your application
>   must first obtain an OAuth access token on behalf of a Twitter user or
>   you could issue Application-only authenticated requests when user
>   context is not required

So in my app, if I am going to have a Sign in with Twitter button, means I am going with the user context based authentication. But I was just wondering do I really have to do it this way..? as to get the information that I want (user's past tweets, his followee/er ids and his profile information) it's enough to get the user's ID so then I can get what I want via the twitter API through Application-only based authentication.

From my understanding, if I'm **not** going to update the user's profile, post tweets for the user or access user's direct messages, I guess I can do this **without** having the user to signin to his account but by just making the user to enter his user ID, right? Am I missing anything with this approach?

Comment: This seems correct. There are certain API calls you can make without needing a user OAuth token, and just your app token will suffice. I know that past tweets and profile information is accessible without a user OAuth token, so you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, you don't *need* the user to authenticate in order to get her profile, previous tweets, run a search, etc.

Really, the only things you can't do are post tweets, change profile information, send or read DMs.

It's important to note that your app will have to abide by the [Twitter Rate Limits](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits) - if your app is only used by a few people, it should be fine.  If the app gets popular, you will need to implement sign in so that each user has their own limits.

Comment: good point! -  "you will need to implement sign in so that each user has their own limits."